# Socket.io + IIS 10 + reverse proxy setup

Tags: iis, socket.io, reverse-proxy

The goal is to host a socket.io server on the same port and domain as my website, hosted on IIS 10 using a reverse proxy. And Ideally configure SSL in IIS rather than the socket.io app.

From what I read, this can be achieved using a reverse proxy URL rewrite rule.

However my javascript client application is showing this error:

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'serve://dist' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 502.`

I have setup a reverse proxy URL rewrite rule to match (regex) the URL `socket\.io\/(.*)` and rewrite it to `localhost:8001/{R:0}`

My web.config contains this:

```xml
<rewrite>
      <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="socket\.io\/(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="localhost:8001/{R:0}" />
         </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

I don't see anywhere where you can differentiate between http:// and ws://.

I honestly don't have a clue what I'm doing. A lot of the stuff I read online is outdated and really not very helpful.

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: I guess this isn't possible?